# Changing diameter of Angular material spinner breaks it

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

This is my code

```
<mat-progress-spinner  [diameter]="50" mode="indeterminate" ></mat-progress-spinner>
```

If i remove the `diameter` it will work properly but if i add `diameter` it will just show up as a circle and not spin.

Is there a way to resize it to make it smaller?

Comment: there is no problem with your code, if you change 50 to 20 it will work fine.

Comment: I do not see an issue there. Can you try to reproduce the issue on stackblitz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change value diameter like this:

```
<mat-progress-spinner  [diameter]="50" mode="indeterminate" ></mat-progress-spinner>
<mat-progress-spinner  [diameter]="30" mode="indeterminate" ></mat-progress-spinner>
<mat-progress-spinner  [diameter]="10" mode="indeterminate" ></mat-progress-spinner>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-progress-spinner)

Answer (score -3):

If you can't get the "[diameter]" property to function correctly, you can always alternative set the height and width separate

```
<mat-spinner style="width:40px; height: 40px" color="primary"> </mat-spinner>
```